# Python API functions called in unexpected order

Tags: python, flask

I'm a fullstack developer (mainly php+js) and started to experiment with python. My python knowledge is like 5 days old and I'm facing strange problem with order of code execution.
Lets start with the code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from libs.dullapi import Dullapi
from libs.db_manager import DbManager

app = Flask(__name__)
db = DbManager()
dullapi = Dullapi(db)

# Removed after first comments
#@app.route('/')
#def main():
#    return dullapi.hello_world()

@app.route('/begin-interrogation', methods=['POST'])
def newHole():
    return dullapi.newHole(request)
```

**db_manager.py**

```
import sqlite3
class DbManager:
    _conobj: sqlite3.Connection

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._conobj = sqlite3.connect('../sol.db', check_same_thread=False)

    # Removed after first comments
    #def holes(self):
    #    dbres = self._conobj.execute('SELECT * FROM holes')
    #    return dbres.fetchall()

    def getConnection(self) -> sqlite3.Connection:
        return self._conobj

    def execParams(self, query: str, params):
        cursor = self._conobj.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        self._conobj.commit()

    def end(self) -> None:
        self._conobj.close()
```

**dullapi.py**

```
from flask import Request
from libs.db_manager import DbManager
import time
import uuid

class Dullapi:
    db: DbManager

    def __init__(self, db: DbManager) -> None:
        self.db = db

    # Removed after first comments
    #def hello_world(self):
    #    data = self.db.holes()
    #    self.db.end()
    #    return {
    #        "ewhat": 14,
    #        'holes': data
    #    }

    def newHole(self, req: Request):
        newHid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.db.execParams('INSERT INTO holes (hole_id, creator_id, created_at) VALUES (:hid, :cid, :cat)', {
            "hid": str(newHid),
            "cid": req.get_json()['uid'],
            "cat": int(time.time())
        })
        self.db.end()

        return {
            'rid': str(newHid),
            'status': 1
        }
```

And `/begin-interrogation` endpoint gives me this error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.` with traceback indicating error on line where `self.db.execParams` is called.

This is very simple code - I know, but I did a lot different APIs with "this" idea of database manager class without problem like this - but only in PHP.

Is Python multithreaded like for each function call or somehow calls functions asynchronously?

**Edit:**
Problem disappears when I remove `self.db.end()` line from `dullapi.py` method `newHole`

Comment: Did you call `/` first? Because that calls `Dullapi.hello_world` which calls `self.db.end()` which closes the database connection, so subsequent uses of the same DB connection will fail.

Comment: No. Please see question again - I removed all "hello world" code (commented out in code samples) and problem still is there.

Answer (score 0):

Like mipadi said, you likely already closed the connection to the database with a different request. What I usually do is to not make a global database connection objcect, but rather initialize a new connection on every request where I need it. Then I save the connection object in a global variable. Flask has the `g` object for this (`from flask import g`), which is "unique" for every request and can only be used within a [request context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.0/reqcontext/).

Example function you could use to always get a connection, but reuse open ones:

```python
from flask import g

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, "db"):
        g.db = DbManager()

    return g.db
```

In your case it might make sense to incorporate this into your existing `DbManager` class :)

For closing connections after every request you might want to look at [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.0/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_appcontext).

Comment: There is no other request. Please look at question again, I have updated it a bit.

Comment: Yes, your edit makes sense. You only open the database connection once, when you start the server, but close it at the end of the request. After removing the line in your edit, the database connection never closes (from python's side) and will work "forever", but I wouldn't recommend keeping it open like that. The connection might still close if there is idle time and the database server decides to close it.

Comment: Oh, so python has one session through all requests? Not like PHP which shuts down after serving a single request and starts over on next one and so on?

Comment: Yes, you would have to manage your session stuff, like cookies (with the `from flask import session` object), in each request. Apart from `@app.route`, you also have `@app.before_request` (does something before every request) and `@app.after_request` (does something after every request and can alter the response), so you could also set up / close database connections there. Note though, that these are also called on static requests like images and Javascript files.